# When to use node.js and when to use ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, node.js

I had a website , which was coded entirely in php and basic jquery ajax . However after i learned about node.js/socket.io i recoded almost all of the real time stuff that involved ajax using nodejs and socket.io . I am a bit confused as to whether i did the right thing . So my question is when is ajax a more optimal solution than using node/socket ?

Comment: This is like asking if it's more optimal to use carpet for surgery or toothbrush for volleyball. You need to get your terminology right.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Firstly, you should learn about the difference between the two, the answer will become clear.

AJAX are used for simple asynchronous requests. They don't require setting up a Node server and are supported on nearly every browser. They are used when you need to retrieve a piece of information from the server. They do however have the overhead of being sent over HTTP and therefore they need to be a proper HTTP request/response (adds weight).

WebSockets (available in a Node.js/socket.io setup) are used when you access some data frequently or you need to have a live, persistent connection with the server. You can establish a socket connection and send packets from the server to the client. This is lightweight compared to an AJAX solution, however Websockets are not supported by older browsers, and you need to setup a server that will handle such requests.

Socket.IO in particular uses a collection of different techniques so that you can get better browser support: long polling, multipart streaming etc.. This allows you to have that "instant" feedback from the server, however it still in most cases uses HTTP as the protocol. It will however use WebSockets if they are available (i.e. supported by the browser).

Actually in some cases Node.js/Socket.io **will use AJAX**.

If you're not working on an online game or if you don't need to update the state of your application frequently, I would suggest using AJAX instead of a Node.js/socket.io setup.

Comment: +1 Good Explanation. Hope you can expand it a little bit more

Comment: but with each connection my app makes with the server apache allots individual threads to each of them thus consuming up a whole lot of resources , and currently i've setup both apache/nodejs . I mean if i use ajax to update my newsfeed every 20 seconds or populate popups , won't it take up a whole lot of resources ??

Comment: What you have described in the 2nd paragraph is WebSockets, not SocketIO. SocketIO provide *web socket* like support, using whatever transport is supported by the current browser; be it websockets, iframe, long polling or even flash.

Comment: @Matt: OK I should probably clarify that

Comment: @MMM: I think the big point about moving from PHP/AJAX to NodeJS+SocketIO is that NodeJS is much better suited at handling many long running simultaneous connections. PHP uses a thread per request; NodeJS has no such restriction.

Comment: @Matt: Haven't I written that in my summary? "if you don't need to update the state of your application frequently"

Comment: @MMM: I guess it's covered in that sentence, yes :).

Comment: @Matt: If you want to compare PHP and Node.js, you need to assume that he's using PHP.

Comment: @MMM: 1st sentence of the question; *I had a website , which was coded entirely in php and basic jquery ajax .*

Comment: Yeah i used php , and i don't want to code the whole of it in node.js ..

Comment: @AnuragD: You don't have to code the whole website in Node.js, you can use PHP as your "content/layout generator", and use Node.js as a "service provider" which will provide the data the website needs. This of course requires two servers though.

Comment: Yes as a matter of fact i am using php to render my pages , with the templating being handled by smarty , and when the page loads up , i open up a connection with my node server . @MMM

Answer (score 4):

Nodejs is great for applications where you need to keep a persistant connection open between the client and the server. Basically if you want to send realtime data (chat client, game, etc.) between the client and server nodejs is a great option.

With nodejs this kind of persistent connection won't block other requests. Many other langauges like php (where each connection starts a new server process) struggle in such situations and you will likely end up with huge CPU load.

Socket.io and node.js together is an even better option if realtime data with the lowest possible latency is the goal. It will only fall back to long-polling when other technologies aren't supported, its preference is to use web sockets.

Of course both apache (with php) and nodejs can do AJAX, the question should really be whether that's the right way for you to transfer data, we need to know more about what you're trying to achieve!